# Sqlite INSERT statement NOT WORKING

Tags: sqlite, csv

I'm trying the following code to insert data in an SqlLite Database. What I checked:

- The db is created (I can see it in the browser);
- The table codeData is present too (I already created it earlier, with columns code char(10), desc char(50) and price char(10));
- The CSV file is read ok;
- I used a Stringbuilder function to emulate the Java one (works ok!);
- I issued and "alert" to check the syntax of the INSERT command ( 'INSERT INTO codeData (code, desc, price) values("123456","Cardboard 123", "US$ 9,99")' );
- The code run without error messages.

But no data is entered in the table!

Anyone can help me? I think the error is obvious, but after 24 hours trying, I cannot see anymore... Thanks!

```
    tableName ="codeData";
    columns = "code, desc, price";
    str1 = " 'INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + columns + ") VALUES (";
    str2 = ")'";

    function Codes_Import() {

    var db =  openDatabase("db_codes", "1.0", "Code Information" , 1500000); 
    file = ReadFile("PRICELIST.csv"); // open csv
    var lines = file.responseText.split('\n');
    for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++)
    {
      var line = (lines[line]); 
      var sb = new StringBuilder(str1);
      var str = line.split(";");
        sb.append('"' + str[0] + '","');
        sb.append(str[1] + '", "');
        sb.append(str[2] + '"');
        sb.append(str2);
        alert (sb);  //<-- just to check if the INSERT statement is correct.
          db.transaction(function(tx) {
             tx.executeSql(sb);
          });    
       }
    }
```

Comment: From what I can see you begin Transaction but forgot Commit? `tx.commit();` ?

Comment: @jpaljasma The `transaction` function automatically commits.

Comment: Why are you using one transaction for each INSERT statement?

Comment: @CL good to know. Nevertheless the code should be executing. Any errors, e.g. `tx.executeSql(sb, function(result){console.log(result);});`

Comment: @CL, I can use transaction for the whole loop, thanks! That will improve the performance, I think.

Comment: @jpaljasma No, no errors. I put the function(result){console.log(result);} as you suggested. No errors... That is driving me crazy! I tested in Chrome, Safari and Firefox: The database and tables are always there, but empty...

Comment: @jpaljasma Just to be clear: the function(result) returns a [object SQLTransaction].

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here:

> I issued and "alert" to check the syntax of the INSERT command (

```
'INSERT INTO codeData (code, desc, price) values("123456","Cardboard 123", "US$ 9,99")'
```

This is not an SQL statement, but a *string containing* an SQL statement. Why? Because your entire "statement" is wrapped in single quotes. So what you actually do is send some random string to the DBMS. What is it supposed to do with it?

The insert-statement within that string wouldn't be correct either. String fields must be enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes, so the statement should read:

```
INSERT INTO codeData (code, desc, price) values('123456','Cardboard 123', 'US$ 9,99')
```

<strike>Also I doubt your code compiles. In C# you get a compiler error for strings starting with single quotes, as a single code can only wrap one character.
The following line should raise a compiler error:</strike>

```
sb.append(str[1] + '", "');
```

Just realized that this is JavaScript...

So 1st of all, fix your SQL wapper statement:

```
str1 = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + columns + ") VALUES (";
str2 = ")";
```

Then fix parameter concatenation:

```
sb.append("'" + str[0] + "','");
sb.append(str[1] + "', '");
sb.append(str[2] + "'");
```

Comment: @Dittmar Thanks for the help, but doesn't worked... I tried both ways: I even Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V the statement instead of using a variable...

Comment: Another problem could be that `desc` may be a reserved word (`order by desc`). You should still get an error message saying what the problem is.

Comment: @Dittmar Thanks again. I will change the column name to descr (just in case...). I changed the escape sequence ( ' vs " ) and I will try.